# Catching a missing call to await

Tags: c#, async-await

Other than writing my own Roslyn based code analysis tool to find such code, is there a simple way to find calls to methods that return a `Task` object, but that are not awaited?

Comment: [Leave compiler warnings on](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873131.aspx)?

Comment: Perfect, thank you! You should post this as an answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is [already a compiler warning for this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873131.aspx), unless you turn it off or write code explicitly to suppress the warning (such as assigning the returned task to a variable).

Personally, I prefer to have compiler warnings as errors.